# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Eel>=0.11.0

Tags: python-3.x

I want to install auto-py-to-exe by `pip install auto-py-to-exe`.
But I am getting the error -

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Eel>=0.11.0.

I use Windows 10 pro.
This is the pip list:

```
Package    Version
---------- ------- 
cffi       1.15.1 
el         0.0.4 
pip        23.2.1 
pycparser  2.21 
setuptools 68.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, you can try upgrading the Eel library to the required version (0.11.0) by running this command:

`pip install --upgrade Eel==0.11.0`

After upgrading Eel, you should be able to install auto-py-to-exe without any issues. Let me know